# Date covering text

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site.

The blog page all of the sudden puts the meta post info (the date) over top of the text in new posts.

I added some padding to the css which fixed it on the new posts, but now the old ones have too much space between the date and text.

Thanks for any and all ideas about this.

Here is a picture:

[image: my page]

I blurred it for privacy (sorry) but the blue circles to the left are the date.  Without this padding, the far apart text looks normal and the close together part has the date on top of the title and paragraph.

Comment: I know you said you blurred it for privacy, but is there any way we could view this page? I could much more adequately asses the situation if I could view the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<!-- custom styles set at your backend-->` change:

```
.container .eleven.units                    { width: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

to

```
.container .eleven.units                    { /*width: auto;*/ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

It should work.

Or in your grid.css add an `!important` to:

```
.container .eleven.units                    { width: 850px }
```

This will make all of the posts inline.
Then if you want to adjust the space between the date and the text I suggest to remove the `padding: 9px 5%;` and tune the `.container .eleven.units {margin-left: auto;}` to something like `margin-left: 20px;`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!!!!!!

This has been bothering me for so long I am embarrassed to admit it.